# How many storage gaps to add at the end of Base Upgradeable Contracts?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, contract-upgrading

I have read about adding Storage gaps at the end of Base Upgradeable Contracts for reserving storage slots. More detailed explaination in Openzeppelin Docs [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable#storage-gaps).

But what is the exact amount of storage gap to be added in the base contracts?

At some contracts it is
`uint256[49] __gap;`
Sometimes, it is
`uint256[45] __gap;` as seen at [Openzeppelin Contracts Upgradeable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol)
Sometimes 50 slots.

What is the optimum number?

Comment: There is no optimal number. You take some slots you think you are going to need. ~50 slots should be enough for everyone.

Comment: Thank You for your answer! Implementing 50 slots henceforth!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no optimal number as the use of storage gaps is just a convention.

I would suggest you use 50 as in the majority of the examples, but this is really up to you.